# IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size CNN

Tags: python, image, image-processing, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am trying to do a saliency map for a medical imaging CNN like so:

```
from tf_keras_vis.saliency import Saliency
from tf_keras_vis.utils import normalize

saliency = Saliency(model, model_modifier, clone=False)

saliency_map = saliency(loss, S)
saliency_map = normalize(saliency_map)

f, ax = plt.subplots(**subprot_args)
for i in range(len(saliency_map)):
    ax[i].imshow(saliency_map[i], cmap='jet')     <----- error
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

but i get an error. Any ideas?

> IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size

Comment: What is subprot_args? What is the shape of saliency_map?